# What is the best way to query all the subwebs in a site collection with a specified criteria

Tags: 2013

What is the best way to query all the subwebs in a site collection with a specified criteria?
I need to return the last 5 created webs with a specific property.

However, I dont know if this is disposed or not?
and 2nd, if there is a faster peformance way to do it

```
using (SPSite clientSiteCollection = new SPSite(currentUrl))
            {
foreach (SPWeb web in clientSiteCollection.AllWebs.Select(c => c.Properties["WebTemplate"] == "xx").OrderByDescending(d => d.Created).Take(5))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unsure if you are disposing each and every object that requires a disposal better use a tool called [SPDisposeCheck](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck). As i can see in your code you are not creating a new instance of SPWeb so I dont think you are offending anything. but, if you are using the 5 SPWeb got from the AllWeb i mean having an SPWeb from the AllWeb. `i.e SPWeb web = clientSiteCollection.AllWebs[0];` then you really need to dispose this one.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to dispose the SPWeb objects accessed via AllWebs, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx#SPDisposeCheckID_130.

I'm not sure if you can query on a specific property, some 'available sites' lists are better created via search (especially when you need security trimming). But reading your requirements, you might be better of creating a feature receiver in your webtemplate, and registering the creation of a site in a central list.